# redirect non existing subfolder, but allow if URL contains a keyword

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have read lots of threads about htaccess redirect, but none really match my situation, albeit quite simple, got me pulling my hair out.

for example I have a site with this structure:

```
 root
 -gallery.php
```

And I have already implement htaccess rule to hide .php extension.
How do I catch the following events:

1. mysite.com/nonexistingfolder would go to mysite.com/404.php
2. mysite.com/gallery/nonexistingfolder would still load mysite.com/gallery, so that I can catch the /nonexistingfolder as a $_GET inside mysite.com/gallery.php?

Comment: And what have you tried since you said it got it pulling your hair out?

Answer (score 0):

Append this after `RewriteRule`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_docs/404
```

Replace `/error_docs/404` with the file that shows the error or does something.

Answer (score 0):

For the regular 404 page, use an error document:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

That covers #1, non-existing folder will go there.

For #2 try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^gallery/(\w+)$ /gallery.php?page=$1 [L]
```